# Got playerasync_runAsynchronousCommandOnQueue while playing the playerItem on the AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I have the following trying to play a playerItem on the AVPlayer

```
 let avAsset = AVAsset(url: url)
 let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: avAsset)
 let avPlayer = AVPlayer()
 let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
 playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
 avPlayer.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
 avPlayer.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
 avPlayer.play()
```

And from the console, I always got the following error even though the video can be correctly played

```
[] <<<< Async >>>> playerasync_runAsynchronousCommandOnQueue: Command 3 returned -12784; this async error will be discarded
```

I'm not sure if because the AVAsset is loaded from AWS S3 with the url, any help is appreciated